# Find which servlet a web request will hit

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

Inside a servlet Filter, is there a way to figure out which Servlet a particular request would eventually hit? I need to do Role based security checks based upon Servlets (not URL patterns) , in a filter (due to legacy reasons).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This information is not available by [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

If you're already on Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), then you can get information of all servlet registrations and mappings by [`ServletContext#getServletRegistrations()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistrations%28%29):

```
for (Entry<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> entry = servletContext.getServletRegistrations().entrySet()) {
    String servletClassName = entry.getKey();
    Collection<String> urlPatterns = entry.getValue().getMappings();
    // ...
}
```

You could do the URL matching yourself based on the servlet mappings and the information as obtained by among others [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29)

If you're not already on Servlet 3.0, then you need to parse the `web.xml` and collect all servlets and their URL patterns *yourself*, or to have a copy of it elsewhere. For manually parsing `web.xml`, the [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) may come handy.

Comment: Nice! This essentially allows filter to evaluate servlet annotations. BTW, servletClassName is entry.getValue().getClassName(). Key is the name of the servlet in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

The  `HttpServletRequest.getServletPath()` returns the part of the request URI that resulted in the servlet being invoked.